# How to setup dashboard with all projects view/widget?

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed a sonar web site, a jenkins web site( CI machine).
While CI server build projects and send info to sonar server as sonar client.
There are lots of projects in my sonar server.

I need a way to setup dashboard with all projects view or widget.
Just like [timeline](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/219971) in [sonar demo site](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/)

But when I configure my own sonar dashboard, I think there are **only treemap and list which hava filter**. ( with filter I can get analysis of all projects )

How did sonar demo web site do this?

(Sonar 3.6.2 , CentOS 6.4)

Thanks a lot ~

Answer (score 2):

They are using the views plugin to do it, without (paying for) it you won't be able to do it.

Once you get the plugin, create a view with all your projects, use the view's dashboard as your main dashboard (in manage dashboards) and add the following widgets : "SQALE overview", "issues and technical debt", "timeline", "measure filter as donut chart" and "measure filter as treemap".

That's it, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of the **Global Dashboard**.

Go to **Manage Dashboards** -> And here you can either select a current dashboard or create a new one. You have the option of adding a treemap with the metrics of your choice. Their "helicopter view" and the other features are all an aspect of the global dashboard feature. You can compare your projects and show the metrics or multiple projects through this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
And as I said treemap has filter, which can show more than one projects once.  
I want to setup timeline such as [timeline](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/219971) on sonar demo web site.  
I couldn't find a way...
In my **Timeline of Manage Dashboards** there is only project selection without filter...

Answer (score 0):

Ran in the same situation and after search for workarounds , only find the new product

**Governance**

The Governance product provides the features to gear-up SonarQube from team-grade deployment to enterprise-grade deployment.

http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/

will be able to do that