# sonarqube - creating global widgets

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

This is similar to questions posted here - [How to setup dashboard with all projects view/widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872608/how-to-setup-dashboard-with-all-projects-view-widget) & here - [How to get all projects on a dashboard in multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852310/how-to-get-all-projects-on-a-dashboard-in-multiple-columns?rq=1)

My question is how can we write custom widget that can access list of projects? The sample code for widgets in github is only about ptoject level widgets, whereas I want to create a widget that can be added in the Home Page dashbaord of my sonarqube instance

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this you have to build a plugin, which is going to have that widget. I advice you to take a read at [this nice introduction](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/sonarqube-plugins-3/) . The widgets are actually a small part of plugins and are written using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: i have read your post and used it to develop a project level widget. My question is how do i create widget that can access list of all projects and metrics for each of those projects?

Comment: So you want to have access to all SonarQube's projects from your plugin?

Comment: yes. i basically need a custom dashboard that allows additional filtering of projects based on custom measures

Comment: I think this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703300/sonar-plugin-development-create-a-global-metric